# Routerlink on Home page after Login

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create a Angular app with Login functionality.

I used `ng cli` to generate the blank app. It came with `AppComponent`.

I then created a `LoginComponent` and a `HomeComponent` with functionality as below:

- `LoginComponent` will be the starting point for the app.
- On successful login, the app will land on `HomeComponent`.

My `app.module.ts` is as below:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [AuthenticationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My `app.component.html` is as below:

```
<div id="mainPage">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My `login.component.ts` has this:

```
onSubmit(user){
    this.authenticationService.login(user)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
          this.router.navigate('/home');
      },
      error => {
          console.log("Username or Password is incorrect!");
      });    
  }
```

This works perfectly fine. And on successful login, I land on `home.component.html` which has `home works!` message.

Question: How can I now have multiple router-links in my home page to navigate through different other components/pages. E.g. One component shows User details (`UserDetailComponent`), another component shows User hobbies (`UserHobbyComponent`) and yet another component shows User address (`UserAddressComponent`).

All the examples I see shows addition of `router-links` above `<router-outlet>` tag in `app.component.html`. I don't want that. I want `app.component.html` to just show the login page and I want home page to show all the other links.

Any help on how to go about with this would be great. 
Any link showing this would help me a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Make your `HomeComponent` a module with his own routes. Is that what you aiming for?

Comment: I might be missing something, but isn't moving the routerlinks to the home.component.html what you're looking for?

Comment: @S.Robijns: Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need Home's children as shown below,

## Step:1 - Add child routing for HomeComponent

```
import {UserDetailComponent} from 'path'
import {UserHobby} from 'path'


declarations: [
  AppComponent,
   LoginComponent,
   HomeComponent,

   UserDetailComponent,                       //added
   UserHobbyComponent ],                      //added

imports: [ ...,

   RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,

        children:[                            //children array added
          {
           path:'userdetail',
           component:UserDetailComponent      
          },
          {
           path:'userhobby',
           component:UserHobbyComponent       //UserHobbyComponent at TOP
          },              
        ]
      },

      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
    ])
```

## step:2 - add router-outlet to display Home's children in home.html

**home.html**

```
<h1> home works! </h1>

  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/userdetail" routerLinkActive="active">Detail</a>
    <a routerLink="/userhobby" routerLinkActive="active">Hobby</a> 
  </nav>   


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: So <router-outlet></router-outlet> will be present in both home.html and app.component.html ?

Comment: Yes. `router-outlet` is required in `Home.html` to display Home's children as `router-outlet` is required to display `Home` and `login` in `App.component.html`